# Creating a new Angular CLI workspace using the ng new command gives Data path ".name" should match format "html-selector"

Tags: angular

Hi I'm trying to start a new Angular cli workspace for a tutorial project I've created on StackBlitz.

Having downloaded the project from StackBlitz, unzipped it, I run

```
ng new rustore/src
```

I choose YES for adding Angular routing

and then no matter which CSS option I choose I get

```
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"name":"rustore/src","version":"8.1.0","routing":true,"style":"css"}

Errors:

Data path ".name" should match format "html-selector".
```

I've updated Node, uninstalled and reinstalled Angular/cli

Any help would really be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have angular.json in that project ?

Comment: Hi Tony, yes I do have an angular.json in the project.

Comment: Can you share with me your source code. It's really hard to tell you if I cant look into the code

Comment: can you run `ng new rustore` without src?

Comment: Hi Reza, running without /src gave a different error. ERROR! rustore/README.md already exists.
ERROR! rustore/angular.json already exists.
ERROR! rustore/package.json already exists.
ERROR! rustore/tsconfig.json already exists.
ERROR! rustore/src/index.html already exists.
ERROR! rustore/src/main.ts already exists.
ERROR! rustore/src/polyfills.ts already exists.
ERROR! rustore/src/styles.css already exists.
ERROR! rustore/src/environments/environment.prod.ts already exists.
<cut for brevity>

The Schematic workflow failed. See above.